# Azure Active Directory authentication stopped working suddenly and redirects page to the login/logout page. How can I get it working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory

First in my localhost and then on the live environment Azure Active Directory authentication has stopped working suddenly. It redirects me to the same login/logout page.

I checked for the client id and tenant id they were not changed and they match the ones in azure, it was working fine yesterday just today it stopped.

Sometimes I also get error as Bad request in a plain html.

This is definitely a question regardless of any fixed template of a question you have in mind.

Comment: For such an issue, actually it is difficult for us to give you a solution here. I recommend you to directly create a new an Azure support request, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> select the `New support request` at the bottom of the page, write the Issue type, Summary, etc -> step by step to create the support request. After creating the support request, the Azure support engineer will contact you soon.

Comment: Additionally , i would suggest you to check the logs if any.

Comment: @MohitVerma thanks I did that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the azure portal go to the app registration then choose the application and go to authentication and in the redirect uri append this to your website url

```
/.auth/login/aad/callback
```